# .eml files are not shown in the qlpreviewcontroller-swift

Tags: ios, swift, download, preview, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to show the preview of the files downloaded from a server. The files are downloaded and I open those with the help of QLPreviewController. Many file formats are supported but .eml file attachment is not shown. I need to open the .eml file within my app using some preview controller. I have used QLPreviewController and allow the user to save to Files.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller for a list of supported file formats. If you think EML files should be supported, you should probably file a radar at bug report.apple.com

Comment: help me out to open .eml files in my ios app.

Comment: @Rahul Were you able to fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @CastleErised14 No bro..still not fixed